# Android OutOfMemory Error StringBuilder

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Okay so I am at a loss here, I have been searching for days now to try and find a solution or why I just suddenly started to get this error. The .class that this comes from has never been changed, it has used the exact same `StringBuilder` since release a year ago, but just in the last month I started getting:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 128887990 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 76MB until OOM
   at 
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
```

What my app does is it uses accessibility service to process what is on the users screen and then does other actions from there. Here is my `StringBuilder` that I have not changed since release a year ago.

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
processSubEvent(source, 0, sb);

private void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final int n, final StringBuilder sb) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
      sb.append("\t");
  }

if (source != null){
    sb.append(tools.getText(source));
    sb.append("\n");
    final int childCount = source.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo child = source.getChild(i);
        processSubEvent(child, n + 1, sb);

        child.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

I have noticed on several other post people talk about not using the `StringBuilder` or writing to file and then reading, but I don't think that is an option for me as I must use it in order to process the `AccessibilityNodeInfo`. I have also added `android:largeHeap="true"` to the manifest like other post have suggested. I am stuck and not sure how to fix this error. TIA

Comment: you are trying to allocate 128.88799MB in a single allocation

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy I know what it says it is doing, but I have never changed this method in a year and it has always worked until last month. I do not control what is on the users screen, I just process it for certain apps. So why would it start crashing now? And it doesn't happen on all phones, my note 8 never has this problem, but S8 seems to a lot.